# Google Drive API : How can I have an access token without asking for Authorization everytime

Tags: java, api, google-drive-api, token

I have a problem with Google Drive sync. I can insert, update, delete, get from a specific Drive account as long as I get the access token from the authorization page. 
Does someone has a solution for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read about "offline access" and "Refresh Tokens". By requesting offline access when the user authorizes your app, you'll receive a refresh token which you can use to obtain an access token at any time.

Comment: Thanks for that, but i already checked that page, and I stop to the same problem : to get a credential to build the drive service, you have to get an authorization code. And i don't see where i can manage to find that!

Comment: read the oauth2 official google pages and inside the drive api official page (authorizing requests)

Comment: You don't need an authorization code (or at least, not in the way you suggest). You haven't correctly understood how OAuth works. The (simplified) flow is request->authorization code-> refresh token -> access token. It's a good idea to spend an hour with the OAuth Playground to see how this all works.

Comment: So you are telling me that I have to get the auth code from a http request ? Or I didn't understand at all the playground :D Anyway, thank you for the help, i'm a bit lost in the drive API!

Comment: separate trying to understand the Drive API from understanding OAuth. That will make life simpler. My strong recommendation is that you don't do any coding until you do understand the OAuth Playground.